# Make try/catch routine less verbose with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this Express middleware handler:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  eventsConfig.getEventsConfig((err, val) => {

    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    try {
      req.eventsConfig = JSON.parse(val);
    } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    next();

  });

});
```

I have used this pattern a lot and it's correct but it's verbose and annoying to write every time - is there a less verbose pattern that's correct?

Comment: use promises everywhere, with async/await then you could have everything in a single try-catch

Comment: @AZ_ for using promises `eventsConfig.getEventsConfig` should return a promise instead of a callback

Comment: @KunalMukherjee yes it should, that's why I suggested using promises everywhere, you always can wrap your function when there's no promisified version available.